# Replicate rows based on 2 "times"-columns and set values to 1

Tags: r, dataframe

I got a R data.frame like this:

```
Value EventX EventY
1 2 0
2 1 1
3 1 2
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
Value EventX EventY
1 1 0
1 1 0
2 1 0
2 0 1
3 1 0
3 0 1
3 0 1
```

I used rep() for now to replicate the row based on the sum of EventX + EventY, but I will get the numbers of the first table replicated too.
I could just set them to 1, but when I have values >0 for EventX and EventY, I want them be set like given in the example, so just setting them to 1 is wrong.

here is my minimal code:

```
 z <- data.frame(df[rep(row.names(df), df$EventX + df$EventY),  1:3, drop = FALSE], row.names=NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `apply` is to repeat 1/0 values for each row.

```
do.call(rbind, apply(df, 1, function(x) cbind(Value = x[1], 
                rbind(data.frame(EventX = rep(1, x[2]), EventY = rep(0, x[2])), 
                      data.frame(EventX = rep(0, x[3]), EventY = rep(1, x[3]))))))

#  Value EventX EventY
#1     1      1      0
#2     1      1      0
#3     2      1      0
#4     2      0      1
#5     3      1      0
#6     3      0      1
#7     3      0      1
```

---

Or a similar `tidyverse` approach could be

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_split(row_number()) %>%
  map_dfr(~cbind(Value = .$Value[1], 
       bind_rows(tibble(EventX = rep(1, .$EventX), EventY = rep(0, .$EventX)), 
                 tibble(EventX = rep(0, .$EventY), EventY = rep(1, .$EventY)))))
```

Comment: Thanks so far, applying these on my bigger df I get an "inconsitent length" Error for the first code, the second worked for me but the result is not correct.
Are you sure about the indexing is right? (X,X,Y,X)(X,Y,Y,Y)

Comment: @Nicolas The logic is to create rows with 1 for `EventX` times and corresponding 0 values for `EventY`, and then vice-versa right? Also do you have any `NA` values in the data?

Comment: Yes the logic is right, I got that now.
There are no NA values, but it currently says my "times" argument is invalid for rep(1, .$EventX) - makes no sense to me as there are no NAs and the column is numeric

Comment: I think you have same `Value` for multiple rows. Try using `apply` solution which already is working row-wise or for `tidyverse` do `df %>%
  group_split(row_number()) %>% map_dfr.....`

Comment: Okay thanks, that worked, but the result is still not correct - I got 

Value EventX, EventY \

1 1 0 \

1 2 0 \

3 1 0 \

and the results is

1 1 0 \

2 1 0 \

2 1 0

Comment: @Nicolas Can you try the updated `tidyverse` answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another base R solution:

```
z <- data.frame(Value = 1:3, EventX = c(2,1,1), EventY = c(0,1,2))

z2 <- rbind(data.frame(Value =rep(z$Value, z$EventX), EventX = rep(1, sum(z$EventX)), EventY = 0)
        ,data.frame(Value = rep(z$Value, z$EventY), EventX = 0, EventY = rep(1, sum(z$EventY))))

z2[order(z2$Value), ]
```

Also, since the EventX and EventY variables don't appear to be dependent on each other, here is a `data.table` solution that may help you approach the data.

```
data.table::rbindlist(lapply(z[, -1]
       , function(x) data.frame(Value = rep(z$Value, x), Counts = rep(1, sum(x)))
       )
       , idcol = TRUE)

      .id Value Counts
1: EventX     1      1
2: EventX     1      1
3: EventX     2      1
4: EventX     3      1
5: EventY     2      1
6: EventY     3      1
7: EventY     3      1
```

And here's a `dplyr` and `tidyr` route. I could have also used the `EventY = 0` and `EventX = 0` in the `bind_rows()` call but I didn't.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bind_rows(tibble(Value = rep(z$Value, z$EventX), EventX = rep(1, sum(z$EventX)))
      ,tibble(Value = rep(z$Value, z$EventY), EventY = rep(1, sum(z$EventY))))%>%
  replace_na(list(EventY = 0, EventX = 0))
```